# How to implement a custom Social Identity Provider on Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to integrate a legacy OAuth 2.0 provider which does not support OpenID Connect 1.0 as identity provider on Keycloak.

This legacy provider provides a xml service that returns the user details similar to userinfo.

I see that Keycloak has the concept of social providers but I can’t find any resources of how to implement and register on GUI a new one.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to implement a login with the Greek tax authorities. Have you found a solution to do it through keycloak? I'm having the same issue and I can't get keycloak to not send scope openid at the first redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the documentation in Keycloak that is referring to this sort of providers: [Identity Brokering APIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#identity-brokering-apis).

I also suggest you to take a look at the source code of some custom providers implemented as [Keycloak extensions](https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html). That can be quite helpful.

Implementing a custom identity provider is typically not a straightforward task and there will be a lot of edge cases and unpredictable scenarios. If your Keycloak server can have access to the database of your identity provider (e.g. via a readonly view) then it would be much easier to just implement a custom `UserStorageProvider` that fetches users for Keycloak. All the other stuff will be handled by Keycloak itself. Then you can also have some custom mappers that fetch those user attributes and allowing you to put them inside tokens.